# Iteratively posting via cURL set of Json records in bash

Tags: json, bash, awk, jq

I have set of Json records in file. I would like to post iteratively.
For example file "jsondata.dat" contains following json records

```
{ 
      "json_records":[
             {
               "name": "name_1",
                "mark": "mark_1"
             },
              {
               "name": "name_2",
                "mark": "mark_2"
             }
        ]
}
```

I would like to post each json record i.e.

```
{
   "name": "name_X",
   "mark": "mark_X"
}
```

in separate cURL post. How to achieve this in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `jq` to pipe each record as a single line, then read that output with a `while` loop to pass to `curl`.

```
jq -c '.json_records[]' | while IFS= read -r rec; do
  curl -X POST -d"$rec" "$URL"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather preprocess your file extracting each record with a python script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json

i = 0
for record in json.load(open('raw.json', 'r'))['json_records']:
    open('record_{}.json'.format(i), 'w').write(json.dumps(record))
    i += 1
```

And then process each record_X.json separately with curl:

```
curl host -d recrod_X.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
vipin@kali:~$ egrep 'name|mark' kk -A 1 -B 1 ###A for Above and B for Below
             {
               "name": "name_1",
                "mark": "mark_1"
             },
              {
               "name": "name_2",
                "mark": "mark_2"
             },
```